# HttpHostConnectException when trying to connect to Jenkins Selenium Grid Plugin

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins

I created a Jenkins Selenium Grid using the Selenium Plugin and have registered my nodes.

Now, when I am trying to start the tests on the grid using my machine, I get the following error

```
Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'sample', ip: 'sample', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumDriver
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b', time: '2017-08-29T12:42:44.417Z'
System info: host: 'sample', ip: 'sample', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_74'
Driver info: driver.version: SeleniumDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:667)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:255)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:237)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to CDEA.emea.abc.corp:4444 [CDEA.emea.abc.corp/172.30.217.175] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:359)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:337)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:646)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    ... 30 more
```

I can ping the Grid URL (CDEA.emea.abc.corp) and get a response from the same machine. So, I assume I do not need a Proxy? What could be wrong?

I have configured the Nodes and Master through the Plugin itself, they are configured with Chromedriver plugin and are online.

This is how I initiate the connection,

```
driver = createRemoteDriver(remoteUrl, caps, checkForProxy, settings.getDriverSettings());
```

where RemoteUrl = http://CDEA.emea.abc.corp:4444/wd/hub
caps = Capabilities [{acceptInsecureCerts=true, browserName=chrome, chromeOptions=org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions@3d8a4416, version=, platform=ANY}]
checkforProxy = false

Comment: Please post the command through which you are starting your hub and nodes